# Unable to Link .png Images

Tags: html, png

```
<ul class="icons">
<a href="https://youtube.com/c/#" target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="Buffer1" />
</a>
<a href="http://twitch.tv/#" target="_blank"><img src="twitch.png" alt="Buffer2" />
</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/#" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Buffer3" />
</a>
</ul>
```

This is the code I used, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.. I'd appreciate any help with this.

A .png image is displayed but when I attempt to click it it goes nowhere (as if it isn't even linked at all).

Comment: Your `<div class="bg-animation"> is on top of everything that why your links dont work`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `z-index` to your `#main`. Look below.

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 27em;
    padding: 4.5em 3em 3em 3em;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.75;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10 !important; <---- look here
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, -ms-transform 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Links seems to be ok. Nothing wrong. We need more information's, code, where is wrong, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only wrong I see with your code is using `ul` without `li`

Should be

```
<ul class="icons">
<li><a href="https://youtube.com/c/#" target="_blank"><img src="youtube.png" alt="Buffer1" />
</a></li>
<li><a href="http://twitch.tv/#" target="_blank"><img src="twitch.png" alt="Buffer2" />
</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/#" target="_blank"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Buffer3" />
</a></li>
</ul>
```